# SQL select percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL that hold users and another one holds there subscriptions. There are users may be sign but they do not subscribe. I use the following query to get the count of users that they have not any subscription:

```
SELECT COUNT(social_users.id) FROM social_users LEFT JOIN socials
ON social_users.id = socials.social_user_id
WHERE socials.social_user_id IS NULL
```

The above query works fine and return a number which it is the count of users that have no any subscription.

Now, I want to get there percentage relative to the total number of users. so I tried to make two count SQL queries and divide them as follows:

```
(SELECT COUNT(social_users.id) FROM social_users LEFT JOIN socials ON
social_users.id = socials.social_user_id WHERE socials.social_user_id
IS NULL) / select count(social_users.id) FROM social_users
```

However, this query does not work. So I need to know any other way that allow me to embed two select and the divide them and then multiply the result by 100.

Comment: `SELECT ((subquery1)/(subquery2))*100 As Percentage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
   Select ( (SELECT COUNT(social_users.id) FROM social_users LEFT JOIN socials ON
    social_users.id = socials.social_user_id WHERE socials.social_user_id
    IS NULL) / (select count(social_users.id) FROM social_users))*100 as Percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to query the same tables twice. If you take the user table and outer join with the social table, group by the user id, you can take a count of the subscriptions per user. Those with no subscription will have a count of zero.

Then just feed that into a query which essentially just counts the number of zeros, divides by the total number of users, *et viola*:

```
SELECT  Sum( case TotalSubs when 0 then 1 else 0 end ) NonSubscribers,
        Count( user_id ) TotalUsers,
        100 * Sum( case TotalSubs when 0 then 1 else 0 end ) /
              Count( user_id ) Ratio
FROM(
    select  u.ID user_id, Count( s.ID ) TotalSubs
    from    social_users u
    left join socials     s
        ON  s.social_user_id = u.id
    group by u.id ) x;
```

You also want the `100.0 *` to be the first value in the ratio equation. Consider:

```
select 1 / 3 * 100.0 PostAnswer, 100.0 * 1 / 3 PreAnswer;
```

returns

```
PostAnswer  PreAnswer
       0.0   33.33333
```

Either that or explicitly cast the two terms to be floating point values before dividing. Always be mindful when mixing integers and reals in equations.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try the following query. The assumption that i have made here is that one user can have more than one subscription. This query has the benefit of getting percentage in one query and hence would be more performant

```
select sum(socials.user_id is null)/count(distinct social_users.id) from social_users
left join socials on socials.user_id = social_users.id
```

I had to put distinct on the denominator because if user can have more than one subscription, it would result in more than one rows, if you are sure that there is one subscription per user, you can get rid of distinct and make this query even more performant